Remove the second line in a double vline to replace it with text - tabularray
I have this example to create function variation table with tabularray package, I need to add 0 in place of double vline in the first row, I  added  vline{4} = {1}{text=\clap{0}} but this keep the second line untouched I need to remove it.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\def\tikzmark#1#2{\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=2pt](#1){#2}; }


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$
\begin{tblr}{colspec={|c|lr||lr|},hline{1,2,5}={solid},column{1}={1cm},column{2-Z}={1.5cm},vline{4} = {1}{text=\clap{0}}}
x                                & -\infty          &&                & +\infty \\ 
\SetCell[r=3]{c,bg=blue!20}f'(x) & \tikzmark{A}{$1$}&&                    & \tikzmark{C}{$+\infty$} \\
                                 &                  &&                    &         \\
                                 &                  &\tikzmark{B}{$-\infty$} &\tikzmark{D}{$-\infty$}&          \\ 
\end{tblr}
$
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt, overlay,remember picture,>=stealth]
\draw[->](A)--(B);
\draw[->](D)--(C);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{center}

\end{document}



Multiple vlines can be drawn by adding a number inside braces in front of the row selection:
vline{<column>} = {<number>}{<row>}{<style>}

Use
vline{4} = {1}{2-Z}{},
vline{4} = {2}{2-Z}{}

to draw a double line, in the 4th column, starting from the row 2.
You can also adapt the spacing to center the 0 between the double line, using \doublerulesep. Try
vline{4} = {1}{text={\kern \doublerulesep\relax\clap{0}}},

Example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\def\tikzmark#1#2{\tikz[remember picture]\node[inner sep=2pt](#1){#2}; }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$
\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={|c|lrlr|},
    hline{1,2,5}={solid},
    column{1}={1cm},
    column{2-Z}={1.5cm},
    vline{4} = {1}{text={\kern \doublerulesep\relax\clap{0}}},
    vline{4} = {1}{2-Z}{},
    vline{4} = {2}{2-Z}{},
  }
  x                                & -\infty          &&                & +\infty \\
  \SetCell[r=3]{c,bg=blue!20}f'(x) & \tikzmark{A}{$1$}&&                    & \tikzmark{C}{$+\infty$} \\
  &                  &&                    &         \\
  &                  &\tikzmark{B}{$-\infty$} &\tikzmark{D}{$-\infty$}&          \\
\end{tblr}
$
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt, overlay,remember picture,>=stealth]
\draw[->](A)--(B);
\draw[->](D)--(C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}

\end{document}


